# How do I modify a Spring application.yml file during deployment in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

My Spring app uses the standard application.yml file to define a connection to a database. I don't want to check any production credentials into the source code or resulting WAR file, and so need a way to modify the YAML file during deployment to include these production secrets.

Is this something I can do with Azure Devops, short of scripting the extraction of the WAR file, doing a find and replace on the file and repackaging it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward way i can recall is to:

- use [Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) for the .war file
- use [Replace Tokens Taks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to lookup your db connection string
- use [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to archive back to war

you have two options for storing your production secrets:

1. Use variables, or variable groups to store your secrets and mark them as "secrets"

[image]
[image]

2. Use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops) to store your secrets and inject them in the pipeline

The replace tokens task uses prefix and postfix tokens to lookup your connection db and the name inside this tokens matches the variable name. e.g. for a token in your yaml "#{db_connection}#" you should create a varible named db_connection in your ADO variables.